# Casting ExpandoObject to dictionary creates nullable reference warning

Tags: c#-8.0, expandoobject, nullable-reference-types

I have nullable reference types turned on and I have the following block of code:

```
    ExpandoObject? e1 = null;

    ExpandoObject e2 = null;

    ExpandoObject e3 = new();

    var d1 = (IDictionary<string, object>)e1;

    var d2 = (IDictionary<string, object>)e2;

    var d3 = (IDictionary<string, object>)e3;
```

I'm trying to cast the expando object to a dictionary but each cast gives me the following warning:

> Warning   CS8619  Nullability of reference types in value of type
> 'ExpandoObject' doesn't match target type 'IDictionary<string,
> object>'.

How can I suppress this warning?

Comment: `ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object?>`. Or you could use `#pragma warning disable CS8600` and `#pragma warning disable CS8619`

Comment: OK, I don't really want to add the exclusion but changing my cast to IDictionary<string, object?> fixes things. Simples. Thanks